# waiting on past events

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I have a C++ program with a test class with two methods:

```
void IntegrationTestBase::wait_test_end() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_mutex);

    m_cond.wait(lock);
}

void IntegrationTestBase::notify_test_end() {
    XN_LOGF_ITEST_BASE(INFO, "Test end");

    m_cond.notify_all();
```

`m_cond` is a conditional variable, `m_mutex` is mutex.

The flow is that an unknow number of threads might `wait_test_end` and then some other thread might `notify_test_end` and they will all stop waiting.

The problem is that after `notify_test_end` some other threads might `wait_test_end` and they will be stuck in the wait indefinitly.

How can I cope with this?

Comment: I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21757124/1460794) useful when looking for a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to cope with it is understand what condition variable is and what it is not. In particular, it is not a singalling mechanism.

Condition variable protect a certain resource (a real variable, for example). The pattern of using it is always the same:

1. Lock the mutex
2. Check the real variable to see if it contains the value you are interested in
3. If not, wait on condition variable - if yes, use the variable and unlock the mutex.