# Consumer producer multithreading freezes

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, producer-consumer, thread-synchronization

I'm trying to create a simple consumer/producer code for learning, in which a producer pushes numbers into a stack, and consumer threads print the numbers, heres what I got:

```
const int N_THREADS = 10;
const int N_TESTS = 100;
bool finished = false;
queue<int> q;

void produce()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N_TESTS; i++)
    {
        q.push(i);
        cv.notify_all();        
    }
    finished = true;
}

void consume()
{
    while (!q.empty() || !finished)
    {   
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
        cv.wait(lock, [] {return !q.empty(); });
        int i = q.front();
        cout << i << endl;
        q.pop();
    }   
}

int main()
{
    //thread that will be used for producing
    thread producer(produce);
    
    //vector of consumer threadss
    vector<thread> consumers(N_THREADS);
    for (int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++)
    {
        consumers[i] = thread(consume);
    }

    //joining all threads
    producer.join();
    for (int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++)
    {
        consumers[i].join();
    }
    
    return 0;   
}
```

However, when i run the code it prints the numbers but it just freezes, it never ends:
[image: Console]

What can be done for it to end?

Comment: Doesn't look like the producer is guarding itself against simultaneous access of the queue.

Comment: `while (return !q.empty() || !finished)` this is legal? I have legitimately never seen this before...

Comment: `std::queue` is not a thread-safe data structrure. You may not using it from multiple threads at once without synchronization.

Comment: @Borgleader what do you mean?

Comment: @user4581301 How could i guard itself against those simultaneous access?

Comment: @DanielLangr What other data structure would you recommend?

Comment: @cheveuxdelin By using it only inside critical sections protected by a mutex, for example. Alternatively, you can use some thread-safe (possibly lock-free) queue, but these are not provided by C++ itself.

Comment: @Borgleader was a typo, I've edited it but it wasn't the problem anyway

Comment: @Borgleader compiler spits a warning, but seems to eat it. But is a `return` statement convertible to `bool`? Smurfed if I know. Never tried it. Correction: Compiler HATED it. Hate-hate-hate.

Comment: here is thing when you code finished processing 100 item it may block at `cv.wait()` and wait for notification and because your code finished and dont send notification any more(from producer side) it will block at `cv.wait()` and in consequence it will not check your while condition.

Comment: @N0ll_Boy you're onto something there. You should formalize that thought into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

i spotted some bugs on your code.

first why you call `notify_all()` you pushed just one element i think it's better idea to call `notify_one()`.

imagine this senario:
producer push one element then call `notify_all()` then others threads wakeup one of them will take mutex and do work and pop element and then other thread check condition and see queue is empty and then they will go to sleep(waste of resource).

another important bug is that when producer finished his work it will return at this moment may queue still has element in this case some thread will wait for notification but since producer exited and therefore producer will not send notification anymore and it will cause some threads block at `cv.wai()`. even it's notify condition variable it will block because condition of `!q.empty()` return false(because `q.empty()` is already true after producer finished).

in order to fix this code you should modify some part of your code.

first i recommend you to also acquire mutex when you are pushing to queue because it is possible that you face race condition(in here you are using queue i dont think it will happened here but if you use vector you will definitely see).

because code block at `cv.wait()`(but beware some thread will exit because they will notified before producer finished and after producer finished they are going to check while condition and they see finished variable is true therefore they have chance to exit but other thread will block at `cv.wait()`). in order to fix this problem you should put another condition in your condition variable:

```
cv.wait(lock, [] {return !q.empty() || (finished && q.empty()); });
if (finished && q.empty())
        break;
```

and your code exit successfully.

i also recommend you to read this topics:

[C++11 Can I ensure a condition_variable.wait() won't miss a notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706209/c11-can-i-ensure-a-condition-variable-wait-wont-miss-a-notification)

https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables

Answer (score 0):

What is `cv` and `m` in your code? I may guess them, but [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be better.

`q.empty()` and `finished` in `consume` is accessed without the guard. Move `unique_lock<mutex> lock(m)` before that access. The condition in the while loop looks wrong. Should not it be `while (!finished)`?

```
void consume()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
    while (!finished)
    {   
        cv.wait(lock, [] {return !q.empty(); });
        int i = q.front();
        cout << i << endl;
        q.pop();
    }   
}
```

`produce` can notify listeners when there is no one. You don't lock the queue before modifying.

```
void produce()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < N_TESTS; i++)
    {
        q.push(i);
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_all();        
        lock.lock();
    }
    finished = true;
}
```